# How can I create a private network for 2 dedicated hosting servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008

At home I can put a cable between 2 computers, what can I do if it is 2 dedicated servers hosted at a hosting company ?

Update: I would need to have same behavior than a private network to access for example a database from a webserver on these machines.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the hosting company to put a cable between the two servers?

Alternatively, you could set up a VPN on one machine and have the other connect to it, or do it the poor man's way with SSH tunnels. (I'm assuming here that you want the security, rather than the speed, of a crossover cable.)

Comment: I would need to have same behavior than a private network to access for example a database from a webserver on these machines.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a product to create a VPN between the computers via the Internet, such as :

[Comodo EasyVPN](http://easy-vpn.comodo.com/)
[LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/)

Comment: LogMeIn is more like remote desktop. Comodo maybe but see my update: I would need to have same behavior than a private network to access for example a database from a webserver on these machines.

Comment: @user75875 LogMeIn (the product) is indeed a remote desktop system, but Hamachi (the product) from LogMeIn (the company) is a VPN system.

Comment: LogMeIn Hamachi (not same as LogMeIn) creates a private virtual network across the Internet. All traffic across this private network is encrypted and so is quite secure.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create an encrypted connection, there's no need for a full VPN – you can use the IPsec feature in Windows. Define a policy to require IPsec (probably with a static key) for the other server's IP address.

Comment: What I need is to have same behavior than a private network to access for example a database from a webserver on these machines.